# How to create interaction terms in a regression model

Tags: regression, interaction

I am doing some research on the interaction term in linear regression.

say, I have 2 predictors, $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$, which interact with each other.

A common practice is to create a new factor $X_{3}=X_{1}*X_{2}$. I am wondering why it is multiply not anything else. Why not $X_{3}=X_{1}/X_{2}$, why not $X_{3}=X_{1}*X_{2}*X_{2}$?

Can anyone give me any clue?

Comment: Could you please explain what your notation means?  Both conceptually and abstractly, "factors" are merely *indicators* of some kind of condition: "this subject is male," "this fruit is an orange," and so on.  Thus mathematical operators like "*" and "/" make no sense unless they are specifically defined.  What is your definition of "/" and what exactly do you mean by "interaction"?

Comment: @whuber I think this question is perfectly fine if you interpret $X_1$ and $X_2$ as everyday, continuous right hand side variables and ignore the word "factor?" I don't think the OP is using factor in the statistics, R sense of the word as a categorical variable, but perhaps user152503 can clarify. I interpret the question as, "why is the default to fit a multivariate polynomial instead of some other functional form?"

Comment: @Matthew Yes, those are plausible interpretations as well.